# With a 2 year work permit for Canada, can I apply for a long stay visa for my mother?

Tags: working-visas, canada, dependent-visa, express-entry

I am from Sri Lanka and I have received a 2 year work permit for Canada. Is it possible to get a long stay of visa of some kind for my dependent mother as well? The state is British Columbia.

Comment: Your mother can only get a regular visitor visa while you are on work permit. You can however sponsor or apply for a super visa if you become a permanent resident.

Comment: How long will this regular visitor visa will be valid for?

Comment: @mayooran How long does she plan to visit for? The maximum is 6 months, depending on the decision of the Border Services Officer at the port of entry https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/eligibility.html

Comment: @Traveller Since she’s old and alone, I would like to have her there on a longer stay. My employer said I can apply for PR after first day at work and assistance from my hiring manager. Do you know how long it would take for PR to arrive since applying?

Comment: @mayooran That’s a different question